# Conforming to Protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift development and am struggling while trying to do some tutorials (I know, they are step by step, but apparently I must have messed up somewhere along the line and now I can't figure out for the life of my why it isn't working. I am not very good at debugging and lack a solid understanding of the foundation of the language. If anyone could help point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

I've tried commenting things out to try and get it as "bare bones" as possible while still being able to "conform" but I am pretty stuck at the moment.

Here is the code:

Error received on this class:

```
final class ForecastAPIClient : APIClient {

    let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration
    lazy var session : NSURLSession = {
        return NSURLSession(configuration: self.configuration)
    }()

    private let token : String


    init(config: NSURLSessionConfiguration, APIKey: String){
        self.configuration = config
        self.token = APIKey
    }

    convenience init(APIKey: String){
        self.init(config: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), APIKey: APIKey)
    }

    func fetchCurrentWeather(coordinate: Coordinate, completion : APIResult<CurrentWeather> -> Void){
        let request = Forecast.Current(token: self.token, coordinate: coordinate).request
    }

}
```

trying to conform to this protocol:

```
protocol APIClient{

    var configuration : NSURLSessionConfiguration { get }
    var session : NSURLSession { get }

    init(withConfig: NSURLSessionConfiguration)

    func JSONTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completion: JSONTaskCompletion) -> JSONTask

    func fetch<T>(request: NSURLRequest, parse: JSON -> T?, completion: APIResult<T> -> Void)

}
```

Sorry if this is already answered.. I searched and read through some other posts, but I still wasn't able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error message and console output?

Comment: Well your protocol defines the `fetch` and `JSONTaskWithRequest` methods as well as `init(withConfig:)`, and you don't implement any of these in your `ForecastAPIClient`...

Comment: " while still being able to "conform"". Conform to what? Conform to the protocol? There's nothing conforming to any protocol anywhere. What do you think conform means? Go back and read tutorials on what conform means and what a class needs to do in order to conform to a protocol. Putting ":  APIClient" after the name of ForecastAPIClient does not make it conform to APIClient.

Comment: @originaluser2 -- I am following a tutorial, and in the video I was using he doesn't implement any of those but still doesn't receive the error that I am.

Comment: @AMomchilov   the build fails, no console output. The error is "Type 'ForecastAPIClient' does not conform to protocol 'APIClient'

Comment: @ThePumpingLama The error that I get is "Type 'ForecastAPIClient' does not conform to protocol 'APIClient' -- I just assumed that meant that I was missing a connection somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you haven't got to the end of the video or it skipped a bit? If you have then that just does not make sense. A protocol doesn't *do* anything, it has no code that executes and does anything.  Your APIClient protocol isn't doing anything. The *doing* part of the code get supplied in the class that implements the protocol. If the video has no implementation of APIClient then it can't do anything and the protocol is pointless and useless. Therefore I simply cannot believe the tutorial does not implement the protocol somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps that could be it.. maybe we are running different versions of xcode and that is why I am getting the error. I stopped the video once I saw I had errors and he didn't. I'll continue on to see if it goes away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your class isn't implementing two of the methods from the protocol:

```
func JSONTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completion: JSONTaskCompletion) -> JSONTask
```

and

```
func fetch<T>(request: NSURLRequest, parse: JSON -> T?, completion: APIResult<T> -> Void)
```

Also, your class has an initializer with this signature:

```
init(config: NSURLSessionConfiguration, APIKey: String)
```

When the protocol requires:

```
init(withConfig: NSURLSessionConfiguration)
```

Comment: Ok, I will look into this in a moment. Thank you

Comment: This is what it was. It had to do with the Init(config) method that was implemented in the struct. I don't know how the guy did it but he must have made the edit outside of the video because others had the same issue as me. Thanks for the help.